# What is happening in array ( 'value' => array() || array() )

Tags: php, arrays

I encountered the following array option and can't figure out what it actually does.

#### input

```
$info = array(
    'input' => $input,
    'type' => array( 'last_name' => 1 ) || array( 'first_name' => 2 ) || array( 'full_name' => 3 ) || false,
    'syntax' => true || false,
    'output' => $output
    );
```

This $info array returns the following when $input = 'A' and $output = 'B'

#### output

```
array(
    'input' => 'A',
    'type' => true,
    'syntax' => true,
    'output' => 'B'
    )
```

I know that "||" means "OR" in an "if" statement but why douse it give "true" at the "type" value?

And why douse it choose true and not false  at the "syntax" value?

Any help is appreciated,
Thanks

Comment: any not empty or null or false or 0 value in if is true so array with one element is true. So `array( 'last_name' => 1 )` is not empty and thats why it is true

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
array( 'last_name' => 1 ) || array( 'first_name' => 2 ) || array( 'full_name' => 3 ) || false
```

This sentence is conditional statement it evaluates to true or false , its different that we are using it in if condition and do the processing based upon its out put. But You can use it as assignment also. and `array('xyz' => 1)` is creation of associateve arrays and in boolean comparision if you can make array it will return true and in OR condition true or false will return you true as a result. so You are getting true as result

Answer (score 0):

At syntax either of the one condition will happen and that is for sure... so its true